# Client-Side events of button(Devexpress control) in MVC5

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress

How to implement client-side events of button(Devexpress controls) in MVC5 using Razor.

I have tried this one but click event isn't firing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnClick(sender, args)
{
    alert("Click");
}
</script>
@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "Button";
    settings.Text = "Submit";
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(sender,args){ alert('Click'); }";
}).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;`
and replace `settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(sender,args){ alert('Click'); }";`
with `settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "OnClick";`